# PayPal sandbox anomalies

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When testing some donations on my local machine, I set various key=value pairs to do various things (return to specific thank you page, get POST data from PayPal and not GET data and others) I also built my code around the response from the PayPal sandbox.

BUT, when my code goes to the production server and we switch on live payments and test with real accounts and money, a few strange things happen;

1. We get a GET response from PayPal - the URL is filled with crap.
2. We get no transaction details. This is the biggie, no name, no txn_id, no dates, nothing. We get a handful of keys etc, its not totally empty and the payment has gone through, but nowhere near the verbosity of the sandbox.

Curious about why this might be? It doesn't really make sense to have a sandbox (or dev environment) that is substantially different from the production environment. Or, am I missing something?

**EDIT**: Still no response to my question in the [PayPal Developer Forums](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sandbox/sandbox-return-different-production%20%22PayPal%20developer%20forums). I don't even get a donation amount back from PayPal. Is this a setting maybe?

**EDIT #2**: Two of you have suggested to check PDT and Auto-Return. The data analytics guy for the project only 2 hrs ago suggested the same. I have asked the client to confirm this. I can't see a setting for it in the Sandbox so can assume that it is enabled by default?

Comment: I use Sandbox frequently and never had that kind of behavior. Hope this information helps.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, try to contact paypal support.

Comment: Thanks guys, will contact them and update when I get more info.

Comment: Nothing yet from the PayPal forums. :(

Comment: Are you sure you have all of the PDT and Auto-Return stuff configured the same on your live account as you do on the Sandbox account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have all of the PDT and Auto-Return stuff configured the same on your live account as you do on the Sandbox account?  There hasn't been much help from PayPal in the x.com forums.  I'd recommend posting a ticket to www.paypal.com/mts, although, they've been a little bit slow there, too.  If you login to your account, though, and go into the Contact by Phone section, you'll see a direct phone number for tech support.  This is probably your best bet.

Comment: Very funny you mentioned this. I was chatting to the data analytics guy for the client site and he suggested the same. There appears to be no setting for PDT in the sandbox, so maybe enabled by default? Either way, I have asked the client to confirm whether it is enabled or not.

Thanks!!